# Batch normalization variance calculation

Tags: deep-learning, unbiased-estimator, batch-normalization

In [batch  normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) the variance calculation during the training phase is done by ($x_i$ are the individual elements in the training batch of size $m$)

$\sigma_B^2 = \frac 1m \sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i - \mu_B)^2$
where $\mu_B = \frac 1m \sum_{i = 1}^{m}(x_i)$

and during the test time we calculate the population statistics for the same as

$E[x] = E_B[\mu_B]$ and $Var[x] = \frac{m}{m-1}E_B[\sigma_B^2]$ (as you can see the unbiased estimate of population variance is calculated during the test time as we are building the model to predict the population distribution)

Would it not seem more logical that bias correction be done during training phase itself and subsequently its expected value can be used without the $\frac {m}{m-1}$ correction factor. i.e

During training:

$\sigma_B^2 = \frac 1{m-1} \sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i - \mu_B)^2$
where $\mu_B = \frac 1m \sum_{i = 1}^{m}(x_i)$

and during test time:

$E[x] = E_B[\mu_B]$ and $Var[x] = E_B[\sigma_B^2]$

Comment: Hi! I find the same issue very confusing and I'm just discovering now how different NN frameworks are vague /inconsistent about this point. 5years later, did you arrive at any conclusion??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be more logical, although equivalent both ways. I was able to find a bit of discussion on this [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1410).

It looks like the original authors later implied that *both* training and test time should use the unbiased variance. Also the actual implementation in many libraries is not completely consistent with what is described in the paper.

Comment: Feels less lonely knowing someone else had the same issue haha. Many many thanks for the effort in answering and sorting through internet to find that link.